# Using Pixhawk Instead of BGC

Tags: components

I know most gimbles has BGC in it. But I wanted to use Pixhawk's stabilization feature instead of using BGC. Do you know any examples(video, web article, etc.) which talks about how to make it? If so, can you provide that/them?

I made reserach for so long but couldn't found anything about it. Because it's rarely used.